# pytest!! Path setting doesn't work : --json-report-file= path

Tags: python, pytest

I am saving the report via -json-report.
However, I want to save it to the desired path, but it is not saved.

**refer to the page**
https://pypi.org/project/pytest-json-report/

**file tree**
I want to save it as a file named 'report.json' in the 'Reports'folder.
The test runs in the 'TestCases' folder.

```
|____Pages
| |____BasePage.py
| |____SignUpPage.py
|____TestCases
| |____BaseTest.py
| |____conftest.py
|____Reports
| |____report.json
```

**I tried**
All of the cases below failed. (The file was not saved...)

```
pytest test_mock.py --json-report-file ../Reports/report.json
pytest test_mock.py --json-report-file=../Reports/
pytest test_mock.py --json-report-file=../Reports
pytest test_mock.py --json-report-file=..\Reports\report.json  
pytest test_mock.py --json-report-file "../Reports/report.json"
pytest test_mock.py --json-report-file="../Reports/report.json"
pytest test_mock.py --json-report-file=/Users/myname/code/python/Reports/report.json
```

What should I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [looks like you need to pass](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-json-report/#usage) `--json-report` in order to get the report and `--json-report-path=PATH` is yet another option to specify the path (i.e. not use the default). Note the last example in the link.

So, you need something like

```
pytest test_mock.py --json-report --json-report-file=../Reports/report.json
```

Not sure if you need to specify file name or if omitted it will use the default one.

Comment: Oh my oh my oh my god .. This is very accurate and works well. :) ( If the file name is omitted, it is assumed that it is not saved. )

Comment: In order not to save file you need to pass `=--json-report-file=none`. If name is omitted I guess the file is "hidden", at least on linux, as default name starts with dot - `.report.json`